# How to sort Array[Row] by given column index in Scala

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

How to sort `Array[Row]` by given column index in Scala?

I'm using `RDD[Row].collect()` which gives me `array[Row]`, but I want to sort it based on a given column index.

I have already used quick-sort logic and it's working, but there are too many for loops and all.

I would like to use a Scala built-in API which can do this task with the minimum amount of code.

Answer (score 1):

It would be much more efficient to sort the `Dataframe` *before* collecting it - if you collect it, you lose the distributed (and parallel) computation. You can use Dataframe's `sort`, for example - ascending order by column "col1":

```
val sorted = dataframe.sort(asc("col1"))
```

Comment: "It would be much more efficient to sort the Dataframe before collecting it " If it fits on one node (i.e. can be collected) I'll bet it's more efficient to sort after collect :) but in general it won't be possible to collect an RDD, or one wouldn't be using Spark...